# install php-fpm on centos after remoe it

Tags: linux, centos, php, mysql

i install php-fpm and php-mysql and nginx then i remove it and update servers kernel.
now, when i want to install php-fpm ,.. dont install

```
$>uname -a
2.6.32-504.3.3.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Dec 17 01:55:02 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$>yum --enablerepo=remi install php php-fpm php-common php-gd php-mysql

Error: Package: php-5.4.37-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: httpd-mmn = 20120211x8664
           Installing: httpd-2.2.15-39.el6.centos.x86_64 (base)
               httpd-mmn = 20051115
Error: Package: php-fpm-5.4.37-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libsystemd-daemon.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: php-5.4.37-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libxml2.so.2(LIBXML2_2.9.0)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-mysql-5.4.37-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.4.37-1.el7.remi
           Installed: php-pdo-5.5.20-2.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
               php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.5.20-2.el6.remi
           Available: php-pdo-5.3.3-38.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.3.3-38.el6
           Available: php-pdo-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64 (updates)
               php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.3.3-40.el6_6
           Available: php-pdo-5.4.36-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.4.36-1.el7.remi
           Available: php-pdo-5.4.37-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.4.37-1.el7.remi
           Available: php54w-pdo-5.4.36-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.4.36-1.w6
           Available: php55w-pdo-5.5.20-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.5.20-1.w6
           Available: php56w-pdo-5.6.4-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.6.4-1.w6
Error: Package: php-fpm-5.4.37-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: systemd-units
Error: Package: php-mysql-5.4.37-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-fpm-5.4.37-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libpcre.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: php-5.4.37-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libpcre.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: php-fpm-5.4.37-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-5.4.37-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: httpd-mmn = 20120211x8664
           Available: httpd-2.2.15-39.el6.centos.x86_64 (base)
               httpd-mmn = 20051115
Error: Package: php-5.4.37-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: php-cli(x86-64) = 5.4.37-1.el7.remi
           Installed: php-cli-5.5.20-2.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
               php-cli(x86-64) = 5.5.20-2.el6.remi
           Available: php-cli-5.3.3-38.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php-cli(x86-64) = 5.3.3-38.el6
           Available: php-cli-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64 (updates)
               php-cli(x86-64) = 5.3.3-40.el6_6
           Available: php-cli-5.4.36-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php-cli(x86-64) = 5.4.36-1.el7.remi
           Available: php-cli-5.4.37-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php-cli(x86-64) = 5.4.37-1.el7.remi
           Available: php54w-cli-5.4.36-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php-cli(x86-64) = 5.4.36-1.w6
           Available: php55w-cli-5.5.20-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php-cli(x86-64) = 5.5.20-1.w6
           Available: php56w-cli-5.6.4-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php-cli(x86-64) = 5.6.4-1.w6
Error: Package: php-5.4.37-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-5.4.37-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.37-1.el7.remi
           Installed: php-common-5.5.20-2.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.5.20-2.el6.remi
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-38.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-38.el6
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64 (updates)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-40.el6_6
           Available: php-common-5.4.36-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.36-1.el7.remi
           Available: php-common-5.4.37-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.37-1.el7.remi
           Available: php54w-common-5.4.36-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.36-1.w6
           Available: php55w-common-5.5.20-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.5.20-1.w6
           Available: php56w-common-5.6.4-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.4-1.w6
Error: Package: php-fpm-5.4.37-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: systemd-sysv
Error: Package: php-fpm-5.4.37-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libxml2.so.2(LIBXML2_2.9.0)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-fpm-5.4.37-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libsystemd-daemon.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_DAEMON_31)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-fpm-5.4.37-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.37-1.el7.remi
           Installed: php-common-5.5.20-2.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.5.20-2.el6.remi
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-38.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-38.el6
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64 (updates)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-40.el6_6
           Available: php-common-5.4.36-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.36-1.el7.remi
           Available: php-common-5.4.37-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.37-1.el7.remi
           Available: php54w-common-5.4.36-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.36-1.w6
           Available: php55w-common-5.5.20-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.5.20-1.w6
           Available: php56w-common-5.6.4-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.4-1.w6
```

what am i doing :(((( ?

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the remi repository from your machine/server. After that you add this repository.

Then try to install with

```
yum --enablerepo=remi install php php-fpm php-common php-gd php-mysql

wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm

sudo rpm -Uvh epel-release-6*.rpm
```

Comment: Please don't post here just to post links to your website. This is considered spam. Also, check the preview window of the posts and the formatting.